# Excel file not saving on heroku server (Flask app)

Tags: python, pandas, flask, heroku

I created a Flask app with a functionality of updating an .xslx file, which is stored on Heroku server.

However, the file seems to be "reversing" to the original state after some time (usually it's an hour or so). Any ideas on why does this happen?

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_session import Session
from functools import wraps
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)
import pandas as pd


def ania_read_comment():
    comments = []
    comments = pd.read_excel('./static/Dane.xlsx', sheet_name="UwagiOgolne")['Uwagi'].values.tolist()
    return comments


def ania_write_comment(comment):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./static/Dane.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df_old = pd.read_excel(writer, sheet_name="UwagiOgolne")
    data = {'Uwagi': [comment]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Uwagi'])
    df = df_old.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='UwagiOgolne', index=False)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()

    return 1

@app.route('/pobyty', methods=['GET'])
def show_pobyty():
    return render_template("pobyty.html", comments=ania_read_comment())

@app.route("/fixed_comment", methods=['POST'])
def fixed_comment():
    ania_write_comment(request.form['editordata'])
    return redirect("/pobyty")
```